# LM13700 OTA VCF resonance

Tags: filter

I built a variable state VCF from Ray Wilson's book on analog synths. It works well except the resonance: turning it up should yield oscillation, instead it just doubles the gain of the output signal (but doesn't change the waveform). The wiring is correct, the only things is my circuit runs on 0-9V (4.5V virtual ground) instead of -9 - 9V. Any ideas how can I get that resonance working correctly? The said part is R16 and R17. Please disregard the red arrow on the pic.

[image]

Comment: These types of circuit are supply voltage reliant on performance. I've mentioned this to you before regarding this chip used on a VCA.

Comment: The LM13700 has a minimum supply voltage of +/- 5 volts...

Comment: I've found a different circuit that works nicely from 9V. Thank you for the help!